# Best way to structure classes in C++

Tags: c++, class

For a long time I have been thinking about following aspect of classes structure. Let's see we have Style class which stores font size, font color and other font-style settings. We have also a Font class.
And now we have two approaches for describing our tasks. The first one is:

```
class Style {
public:
    unsigned short size;
    unsigned short color; // just for example
};

class Font{
private:
    Style style;
public:
    void setSize( unsigned short fontSize ) {
        this->style.size = fontSize;
    }
    void setColor( unsigned short fontColor ) {
        this->style.color = fontColor;
    }
    void setStyle( Style style ) {
        this->style = style;
    }
};
```

The second one is:

```
class Style {
private:
    unsigned short size;
    unsigned short color; // just for example
public:
    void setSize( unsigned short fontSize ) {
        this->style.size = fontSize;
    }
    void setColor( unsigned short fontColor ) {
        this->style.color = fontColor;
    }
};

class Font{
private:
    Style style;
public:
    void setStyle( Style style ) {
        this->style = style;
    }
};
```

I use Style-object very often in my app:

```
Style style;
style.size = 10;
style.color = 02034023; // doesn't matter :)
font.setStyle( style );
```

So if we define setColor, setFont and other voids in Style class we have loaded them all in our memory (by each copy of Style-object). If we define setColor and others in Font class we have just one copy of setColor loaded in a memory. As I use creating of Style object very often I don't want to load setColor and others in a memory just to have an opportunity to use this class something like this: `style.setSize( 10 );`. Using such technique I load only one copy of setSize and others in a memory.

What do you think about it? Which structures do you use and why?

Comment: You may want to post this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @JID Agreed. This is an incredibly ambiguous question with an example more about code style than anything else.

Comment: Should be migrated to Code Review.

Comment: "class we have just one copy of setColor loaded in a memory" - `setColor` is an implicitly inline function. the optimiser will likely ensure your values are written directly into the Font's data members.  Even if it wasn't inline, there'd only be one copy of the `setColor` function's executable code in memory, no matter how many times it was called.  You'd be better off worrying about the error-proneness, expressiveness and convenience of your interface and forgetting about imagined efficiency and memory issues.

Comment: Very much a style question. As a general rule, each class should maintain its own content. If you where to use the `Style` also to set the style of the `Line` class, then it becomes obvious that the style is the right place to set the `color` and `size`. (The next question is of course how you "restyle" a font or line, do you have to create a new one from scratch, or is there some way to "change the style")

Comment: take a look at Boost.Flyweight

Comment: @JID I disagree. Code Review is for code that is actually being *used* in production. Although it is subjective, it belongs here more than it belongs on code review.

Comment: @TonyD no, I meant: style1.setColor(), style2.setColor, style100.setColor and etc. You have many setColors in your memory, right?

Comment: @JavaRunner: you may call it many times on many distinct style objects, but whether you use your first or second approach the amount of RAM used for data and code during your program execution is likely the same in an optimised build.  Does that answer your question, or am I misunderstanding your thrust?

Comment: @JavaRunner, No as TonyD says, only one copy of `setColor` will be loaded into memory. The only thing that is loaded into memory for each style object is the data, e.g two `unsigned short`.

Comment: @Calpratt I don't see production only mentioned anywhere but on the `2 minute tour` it specifically says `Best practices and design pattern usage` which i think this question definitely fits under.

Comment: @JID the tour specifically says in the *Don't* secstion "Best practices in general (that is, it's okay to ask "Does this code follow common best practices?", but not "What is the best practice regarding X?")"

Comment: @Calpratt I was only suggesting anyway (not saying they had to) as i thought they might get better answers there, i suppose it doesn't really matter though :)

Comment: @ChrisDrew you mean setColor will load only in one copy into the memory? If I understand you right setColor will be something like a shared function for all instances of Style class even if we use something like that: **Style styles[ 10000 ];**? In memory we have only one setColor in this case not 10000 setColors, right?

Answer (score 2):

### Option 1

**Pros**: Partial encapsulation of the `Style` object
**Cons**: You have to provide a method in `Font` for each field in `Style`. This may work for simple application like this, but imagine you would have `Paragraph` class that would have its `Font` and `Content` fields (or maybe more). Then you would have to either use option 2 or rewrite all the methods from `Font` again.

### Option 2

**Pros**: You can fully access the `Style` object from any level of hierarchy
**Cons**: You have to instantiate a new object every time you want to change something. Problems with object lifetime/ownership coming in. (Do I delete the style here? Is it referenced somewhere else?). Style object has no encapsulation.

### My proposal

Use const-correctness with getters:

```
class Style
{
public:
    unsigned short size;
    unsigned short color; // just for example
};

class Font
{
private:
    Style style;
public:
    const Style& GetStyle() const { return style; }
    Style& GetStyle() { return style; }
};
```

This way you clearly state that the ownership of `Style` object belongs to `Font` while also enabling it to be read/changed in given places, i.e.
`font.GetStyle().size = 14;`

Also you can use function signatures to clearly state hat happens with the `Font` inside.

```
void AccessFont(const Font& font)
{
    unsigned size = font.GetStyle().size; // works
    font.GetStyle().size = 16; // doesn't compile
}
```

And again, if you came to a hierarchy with `Paragraph` class as mentioned, you would just add the two getters for `Font` field. You can then pass around the const and non-const version of `Paragraph`.

Comment: Option 2 is a violation of encapsulation and the law of demeter

Comment: I think if the `Style` object is small and not likely to change very often then it is OK to break encapsulation. You can just use value semantics with the `Style` object and you don't need to worry about ownership. On the other hand if the `Style` object gets large or is likely to change it is probably a good idea to encapsulate it.

Comment: Note that in OP's Option 1 the `Style` is not fully encapsulated as they have a `setStyle` method on the `Font`.

Comment: Thank you both, you have a point. Answer edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

**I think either is fine.**

If you are going to go with Option 1, I suggest you don't provide a `setStyle` method so the `Style` is fully encapsulated. That way, clients of `Font` don't even need to know that `Font` contains a `Style` object. Changes in `Style` only impact `Font` and you can even change the implementation of `Font` to not use a `Style` object in the future without breaking clients.

If `Style` is unlikely to change and is just a small object that you are going to pass-by-value then I think Option 2 is fine too.